# \\s, for regular expressions, why we need 2 "\"

Tags: regex

I am doing an regular expression HW, and I got confused about escape icon "\"
For . * ^ () [] + ? | \ (space).

we need "\" to put them in expression if we need to use the actual symbols, but Why we need two "\"? like "\\s".

I thought "\s" will be enough cause I know in unix, "\ " means, I need that space in the input.

Comment: What computer language are you using?

Comment: If your language uses C strings, and no string literals, you will need to use one backslash to escape the other backslash to use a literal ``\`` that is necessary to specify a shorthand class like `\s`.

Comment: In Java needing to use \\ comes from the way the string literals works, and has nothing to do with regular expression notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the effect even in your question. See where you wrote `like "\\s"` ? And your question shows `like "\s"` ?

Because you need to escape `\` with `\\` to get it through the Markdown interpreter that StackOverflow uses and get one `\` out the other end, then you can use that one in your regex.

(And now you've edited around it. But the idea remains - you only need one \ in the regex, but you might need more than one to get it through whatever editor/environment/interpreter/programming language you are using and into the regex engine).

Comment: Thank you so much. Clear than my professor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are, in this instance and a lot of others, used for [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). An escape character means, in (very) short, "the following doesn't mean what it usually does". You've already used this in regular expressions: the `\s` you wrote specifies that the character 's' isn't a regular 's', but a whitespace token.

It also sounds like the language you're using also uses backslashes for escaping strings. This means that a backslash character would normally be an escape character, but for the purposes of the string you're trying to save, you actually want the character `\`—something other than what it usually represents. To do that, you have to use the first backslash to say "the following backslash doesn't represent an escape sequence, as it usually would, but just a regular character".